Keep Android Studio from Indexing a libraries' header files
In short, I do not want Android Studio to index C++ header files which are contained in certain folders, since this process takes a very long time.
I have tried marking them as Excluded in the IDE, but to no avail.
Are there any other options for me?
Preliminary
I am working on a project that contains one of my C++ libraries which, when built for Android, needs to be linked to multiple libraries.

The Eigen linear algebra library (which is header only).
OpenCV Android Release
Boost for Android as prebuilt static libraries that I interface to using the header files

In this scenario, the dependencies (Eigen, OpenCV, Boost) are static files in my Android Studio project and my library is checked out from a separate repository.
My Problem
I do not need to modify the sources of my library inside Android Studio, I only need to link it against the dependencies and build it for use in my Android App.
When Android Studio is launched, it goes through a long process of updating indexes for header files which are not part of my active development process inside the IDE.
I'd rather have Android Studios Linter/LSP ignore them entirely.
The process encompasses indexing > setting up build configurations > indexing again & setting up run configurations which takes about 15 to 20 minutes on my 32GB Ram, 5GHz processor machine. During that time I cannot fully make use of the IDEs features to their full extent. This is annoying and I want to mitigate this issue.

My Question
I have tried Select Folder > Right Click > Mark Directory as > Excluded, but this does not change anything. The header files are being indexed all the same.
Is there anything else I can do to prevent this mass-indexing?
Below I have added my CMake-based build setup for the NDK part of my project, if that helps.
Build Setup
Everything is linked together in a CMakeLists.txt file
# path/to/my_library/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(my_library
    /path/to/stuff.cpp
)

if (ANDROID)
    ### Eigen ###
    if (NOT TARGET Eigen3::Eigen)
        add_subdirectory(eigen)
    endif ()
    if (NOT TARGET prmcl)
        add_subdirectory(prmcl/library)
    endif ()
    ### OpenCV ###
    set(OpenCV_DIR path/to/opencv-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni)
    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
    ### Boost ###
    set(Boost_DIR path/to/boost/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI})
    add_library(boost_math STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(boost_math PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Boost_DIR}/lib/libboost_math_c99.a)
    # amalgamate the used boost libraries
    set(Boost_LIBRARIES boost_math)
    
    
    
    target_include_directories(my_library
            PUBLIC
            ${Boost_DIR}/include
    )
    target_link_libraries(my_library
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        Eigen3::Eigen
    )
endif ()

I can then use my_library to link against my NDK wrapper in the project root CMake file
# path/to/CMakeLists.txt
project("NativeWrapperToMyLibrary")
add_subdirectory(my_library)
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        src/wrapper.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        android
        log
        my_library
)


See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460906 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163185/Gradle-import-Additional-entries-in-srcDirs-cause-too-unspecific-content-roots

So from looking at both issues it seems that there is no existing solution for this. The issuetracker link even ends with a wontfix (infeasible) tag.

Well, infeasible from the Android Studio developers' point of view, because they see this as something that needs to be fixed in IDEA by Jetbrains.
